# Estimating rate of evolution from a phylogeny

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogeny, virus, beast, substitution-model

Any suggestions for the best way to estimate a metric for evolutionary rate of viral sequences of the same species?

I was using terminal branch length from a phylogeny and would quite like to try sub rates but i am really new to this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.